# How can I display a Youtube video in Android app from desired video ID such that the ID is set from a server so that I can change the ID later?

Tags: java, android, mysql, firebase-realtime-database, youtube

I am new to Java and Android Studio.

I am currently working with Android Studio and I am able to load the YouTube video from the video ID, but in my app, I cant keep the video ID static I need to change the ID frequently without requiring users to download an app update. I have tried Firebase real-time database and remote config, but in both of them, the video lags because they download data asynchronously. What is the optimal solution to this problem?

Thank you for helping in advance.

Here is my YouTube video Fragment:

```
package shah.vatsal.kinitro

public class youtubefragment extends Fragment {

private static final String API_KEY = 
"AIzaSyAXjBSS9NVAewJ2Z0Z86JrlHsJbJzoP_Ns";

private static String VIDEO_ID = "mMMerxh_12U";

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.youtube_videos, container, 
false);

    YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.youtube_layout, youTubePlayerFragment).commit();

    youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(API_KEY, new OnInitializedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
            if (!wasRestored) {
                player.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
                player.loadVideo(VIDEO_ID);
                player.play();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult error) {
            // YouTube error
            String errorMessage = error.toString();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("errorMessage:", errorMessage);
        }
    });
    return v;
}
}
```

YouTube Layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/youtube_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure my suggestion doesn't follow the path you're trying to take, but you could easily achieve that by setting a webpage in which the video is put and then loading it from a WebView so as you could simply change the webpage and the video would be updated next time users run the app if you don't set a cache system or you just clear it whether you have it set.

It's way easier than trying to deal with Firebase development environment (which I find complicated), but you may deal with some lag while loading the page if the page isn't well optimized; however you could solve it today by simply setting a Tumblr space, for instance, and from time to time you could just change the link provided in order to showcase different videos.

Even if you want to show other elements in your activity besided the WebView, you could do it with some limitations or you could just insert what you like on the webpage itself (it depends mostly on your real needs).

Here is a [Kotlin WebView sample](https://github.com/QuaestioOrg/android-kotlin-webview) in case you aren't familiar with it and here you can learn more about [WebViews](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView) in general.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion but embedding a video in webview would do the job but would mess up with the environment and the UI of my app

Comment: You're welcome, @VatsalShah! Yes, I really think it's not the best option to deal with your case, but it was the alternative I could think of. And, unfortunately, I don't have experience with Firebase development in order to help you accordingly here.